# Array inside a class in vb .net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

```
Public Class myClass
Public myArray() as String
End Class
```

And to test it

```
Dim m as myClass
Dim c as integer

For i=0 to 9
c = m.myArray.count
m.myArray(i) = i.ToString()
Next
```

Obviously this doesnt work, but this is what I would like and not sure how to approach it.

edit: this works but it seems kinda dinky...

```
For i=0 to 9
c = m.myArray.count
ReDim m.myArray(i)
m.myArray(i) = New String 'in my code its a sub class rather than string
m.myArray(i) = i.ToString()
Next
```

Comment: Arrays need to be initialized. Your code creates an empty array but then it tries to populate it with data. As it wasn't initialized, it had no space to hold any data.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using Lists instead of arrays. This allows you to add items on the fly.

Using your example:

Class:

```
Public Class myClass1
    Public myArray As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

Code:

```
Dim m As New myClass1
Dim c As Integer

For i = 0 To 9
    m.myArray.Add(i.ToString())
    MsgBox(m.myArray(i))
Next

c = m.myArray.Count
```